# Google Cloud DNS failed to load

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I am developing new website using google cloud, but cloud DNS failed to load. Don't know what's wrong with that. Any solutions?

[image: Problem]

Comment: could you put in the code that you tried?

Comment: I just created instance for wordpress. It works perfect. Now I want to link IP with domain name, but Cloud DNS fails

Answer (score 13):

- Go to APIs & services -> Library
- Type DNS
- Click on "Google Cloud DNS API"
- Click on "Enable"

Comment: This is the correct anwer. You may have to wait a few minutes for the error to disappear and the interface to pop up after you've enabled cloud DNS

Comment: In my case the "Google Cloud DNS API" was enabled and still was getting the "Failed to load" message,
I disabled and them immediately enabled it, and only then it started working correctly.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks! This "reset"-variant with disable+enable has helps me. I think it's not a problem with the browser itself. (maybe an issue in the GCP if you have multiple projects)

Comment: @DemiBen-Ari after disabling and enabling all the subdomains which were created earlier will they present or will we loose them

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem this afternoon.  I was using Safari on a Mac, so I thought I'd try another browser.  Sure enough, Chrome loads the page just fine.

Maybe try a different browser? (I had success with a with Chrome in an Incognito window)

Answer (score 1):

you can only 'enable dns' on one project at a time. you will probably have another project dns enabled. disable it, then enable the dns on the project you want to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just enable the API and give the Cloud DNS a couple minutes to load up